# Delete orphans from alternative database using JPA @NamedQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some trouble trying to execute a DELETE from an alternative table using JPA @NamedQuery.

I want to create a *@Schedule task* to schedule a deleting job on some orphans data in **MyEntityDB**.

I compare with *NOT EXISTS* the data in MyEntityDB with other data in OTHER_TABLE and then *delete the ones that are in MyEntityDB and not exists in OTHER_TABLE*.

For that, I created an **MyEntityRepository** interface to create the deleting method.

With that, I want to run the scheduled task.

How should I approach to this solution?

**MyEntity.java**

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "deleteOrphans",
        query = "DELETE FROM MyEntity " +
                "WHERE NOT EXISTS (" +
                    "SELECT NULL FROM OTHER_TABLE ot " +
                    "WHERE ot.ID = :myEntityId)"
                )
})
```

**MyEntityRepository.java**

```
void deleteOrphans();
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA can delete your orphans as soon as the parent is deleted

On the parent-Entity you have to set `orphanRemoval`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval="true")
public List<Orphan> orphans;
```

That way you don't need a scheduled task which "cleans" your database